# Conditionally get second row from join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following 3 tables:

```
mysql> explain runners;
+-------------+------------------+
| Field       | Type             |
+-------------+------------------+
| runner_id   | int(10) unsigned |
| name        | varchar(100)     |
+-------------+------------------+

mysql> explain runs;
+-------------+------------------+
| Field       | Type             |
+-------------+------------------+
| run_id      | int(10) unsigned |
| runner_id   | int(10) unsigned |
| race_id     | int(10) unsigned |
| position    | int(10)          |
+-------------+------------------+

mysql> explain races;
+-------------+------------------+
| Field       | Type             |
+-------------+------------------+
| race_id     | int(10) unsigned |
| date        | datetime         |
+-------------+------------------+
```

Next, I have to display all the races a given runner participated in, something like this:

```
mysql> select runner.name, runs.run_id, runs.position, races.race_id
       from runners
       join runs on(runs.runner_id = runners.runner_id)
       join races on(races.race_id = run.run_id)
       where runners.runner_id = 1;
+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| name             | run_id | position | race_id |
+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
| John Runner      |      1 |        1 |       1 |
| John Runner      |      7 |        3 |       2 |
| John Runner      |     15 |        2 |       3 |
................... more lines ...................
+------------------+--------+----------+---------+
```

Now I should add another column called "win/second" to this query, that will display the name of the runnner that finished second if the current runner's position = 1 or display the name of the winning runner in that race if the current runner's position != 1, but I just don't know how to get this working or even what to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you what you need:

```
select runners.name, 
   runs.run_id, 
   runs.position, 
   races.race_id,
   case
      when runs.position = 1
      then    runnerssecond.Name
      else    runnerswinner.Name
   end as NextColumn
from runners
   join runs on(runs.runner_id = runners.runner_id)
   join races on(races.race_id = runs.Race_Id)
   left join runs runswinner on runswinner.race_id = races.race_id and runswinner.Position = 1
   left join runners runnerswinner on runnerswinner.Runner_Id = runswinner.Runner_Id
   left join runs runsecond on runsecond.race_id = races.race_id and runsecond.Position = 2
   left join runners runnerssecond on runnerssecond.Runner_Id = runsecond.Runner_Id
where runners.runner_id = 1;
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99d13/4).

Good luck.

Comment: Here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99d13/7 , I simplified it to a single additional join with extended condition and removed the case statement as it is not necessary anymore. Thank you!

Comment: Nice job -- hope it helped.  Good luck.

Comment: Yep, it helped a lot! Thanks! If you don't mind, please edit the answer so other people will not need to click yet another link.

Answer (score 1):

This gets the first and second place getters of each race.

```
SELECT r1.race_id,
       r1.runner_id AS First,
       r2.runner_id AS Second
FROM   runs r1
       INNER JOIN
       runs r2 ON r1.race_id=r2.race_id AND r1.position=1 AND r2.position=2
```

You can join this to your other tables to get whatever you want

OK - extension. This is SQL server syntax - it may need some translation

```
select runner.name,
       runs.run_id, 
       runs.position, 
       races.race_id,
       case runs.position
            when 1 then pos.Second
            else pos.First
       end AS [First/Second] 
from runners
     inner join runs on runs.runner_id = runners.runner_id
     inner join races on races.race_id = run.run_id
     inner join (SELECT r1.race_id,
                        r1.runner_id AS First,
                        r2.runner_id AS Second
                 FROM   runs r1
                 INNER JOIN
                 runs r2 ON r1.race_id=r2.race_id AND r1.position=1 AND r2.position=2) as pos
where runners.runner_id = 1;
```

or, simplifying

```
select runner.name,
       r1.run_id, 
       r1.position, 
       r1.race_id,
       r3.name AS [First/Second]
from runners
     inner join runs r1 on r1.runner_id = runners.runner_id
     inner join (SELECT runners2.name
                 FROM runners runners2
                 INNER JOIN
                 runs r2 ON r1.race_id=r2.race_id 
                         AND r2.position=CASE r1.position WHEN 1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) r3
where runners.runner_id = 1;
```

Comment: This solution seems to be the most appropriate to what I'd do because it does not contain sub-queries and it seems to be easier to implement in the ORM I'm using (propel-orm). The only thing about it is that is not complete yet as it does not handle the case when the current runner's position != 1. Please extend the condition and I'll accept this answer.

Comment: It also need one more join to get the runners' name

Comment: You almost the solution.... aaaand it's gone! I liked your solution because it had no sub-queries, but it has now...

Answer (score 1):

The following query approaches this by precalculating the first and second place names, and then joining them in:

```
select runner.name, runs.run_id, runs.position, races.race_id,
       (case when runs.position = 1 then SecondRunner else FirstRunner end) as FirstOrSecond
from runners join
     runs
     on runs.runner_id = runners.runner_id join
     races
     on races.race_id = run.run_id join
     (select runs.race_id,
             max(case when position = 1 then runners.name end) as FirstRunner,
             max(case when position = 2 then runners.name end) as SecondRunner
      from runs join
           runners
           on runs.runner_id = runners.runner_id
    ) fs
    on fs.race_id = races.race_id
where runners.runner_id = 1
```

If you want simple, then just use the subquery:

```
     select runs.race_id,
             max(case when position = 1 then runners.name end) as FirstRunner,
             max(case when position = 2 then runners.name end) as SecondRunner
      from runs join
           runners
           on runs.runner_id = runners.runner_id
```

I thought you wanted the additional information as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It answers my question and I hope it'll help someone but I'll choose Dale's answer because of simplicity to implement in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

To start:

- Step 1: get the first as a fifth column and the second as a sixth column.
- Step 2: use an `IF` on the position column to decide which expression to display